# How to register PostgreSQL in FastReport Open Source

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, fastreport

I'm testing [FastReport Open Source](https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport). Tell me, how can I register my PostgreSQL database in report? I tried to create a report in free Designer Community, but there is only MS SQL. I have understood right that there are only one way to build a report from code with packages from Nuget?

Comment: Does the designer on the Open Source version come with the option to add a dialog to allow the user to enter report parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest build [FastReport Open Source 2018.4.9](https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport/releases/tag/v2018.4.9). It can work with PotgreSQL. The Designer Community edition have a native PostgreSQL connector. Also you need add the [FastReport.OpenSource.Data.Postgres](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastReport.OpenSource.Data.Postgres/) from NuGet in your application.

Execute the following code once at the application start:

```
FastReport.Utils.RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(PostgresDataConnection));
```

Now you should be able to create a new PostgreSQL data source from Designer or from code:

```
Report report = new Report(); 
report.Load(@"YourReport.frx");
//... 
PostgresDataConnection conn = new PostgresDataConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
conn.CreateAllTables();
report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(conn);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer